# An alternative, more concise phrase for "due to even something as insignificant as"

Tags: phrases

I'm looking to improve on the wording of the following phrase shown in bold. While it conveys the correct meaning, "due to even something as insignificant as" seems unnecessarily wordy so I was hoping for an alternative phrase to represent the same idea. I'm also open to suggestions to rephrase the entire sentence.

> Additionally, real estate assets in the same vicinity may be viewed
>   differently due to **even something as insignificant as** home decor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your bolded phrase: remove the word "even." Other options for insignificant are "petty" and "trivial":

> Additionally, real estate assets in the same vicinity may be viewed differently due to something as trivial as home decor.

Further improvements: Change the word vicinity. It could be "block", "neighborhood", "town", "city", or "region" depending on what you're talking about. Also, change "viewed differently" to be more specific. If possible, I would also change "real estate assets" to be more specific to the types of assets you're discussing (homes, apartment buildings, whatever).

Example sentence:

> Other residences in the same neighborhood may be better appraised due to something as trivial as home decor.

Or, for a more extreme change:

> Buyers may be more likely to bid on other homes in the same neighborhood due to trivial things like what decor is present during showings.

In the future, a post like this should be tagged with "phrase-requests" rather than "phrases"